# Obtaining Picard Iteratives in a coupled system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

Obtain the first 5 Picard´s Iteratives of the Cauchy problem:

$(dx/dt) = y $ with $x(t=0)=0  $      and

$(dy/dt)=-\sin(x) $ with $y(t=0)=1 $

The function $x\mapsto \sin(x)$ should be written in its Taylor expansion, and including only the terms that are relevant for the computing of the Iterative in moment.

How can I solve this?

My idea is to express x in terms of y with the first equation (solve this equation without Picard's method), and then substitute this $x$ in the second equation to obtain an equation in terms only of $y$, approximate this for $y$ (with Picard) and then solve the first equation for $x$. Is this way correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you would solve the first equation in its own; the system is coupled.

Picard iteration for first-order systems works the same as for first-order equations; you just integrate a vector-valued function. In your case, writing $z = (x,y)$, we have 
$$z(t) = (0,1)+\int_0^t f(z(s))\,ds \qquad \text{where } \ f(x,y) = (y,-\sin x) $$

So, starting with $z_0\equiv (0,1)$, you get $z_1$, $z_2$, ...  where $z_k$ is within $O(t^{k+1})$ of the exact solution. Therefore, it makes sense to write $z_k$ only up to $t^k$, disregarding higher powers. Like this:

$$z_1(t) = (0,1) + \int_0^t (1,0)\,ds  = (t,1)$$ 
$$z_2(t) = (0,1) + \int_0^t (1,-\sin s) \,ds  \approx  (0,1) + \int_0^t (1,-s) \,ds
=(t, 1-t^2/2)
$$ 
$$z_3(t) = (0,1) + \int_0^t (1-s^2/2,-\sin s) \,ds  \approx  (0,1) + \int_0^t (1-s^2/2,-s) \,ds = (t-t^3/6, 1-t^2/2)
$$ 
and so on.